# Firebug and jQuery

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm trying to debug my js code on my page that includes a jQuery file using Firebug (I'm new to jQuery..and Firebug kinda). However, Firebug is only showing me the 8k+ lines of jQuery code, and doesn't show my code anywhere. Where can I find my code? And is there a way to skip over certain external script files? I tried unchecking the file in the "filename" dropdown in the Script panel, but that doesn't do anything.

Thanks

**Update:** I just realized that when I include the external jQuery file, my inline js code, which is defined right after in `<head>`, isn't even recognized/compiled. None of my event handlers are defined or anything ><
And when I include the jquery file *after* my inline js code, my inline code is compiled and there, but my whole `form` is missing!! WTH is going on!?

Comment: Your code ? !, is your code inline or from external .js source ?

Comment: inline. That's what I meant by its "on my page".

Comment: If there is javascript in your html instead of a js file, it will also be listed in the same list.

Comment: @Marnix That's what I figured..but its not. I ran a search and couldn't find my inline js functions. Also fb is showing me the same num of lines of code as in the jquery file. I can't find my inline code anywhere

Comment: If it's not in the list, update your question. Ask about the not-compiling-problem as well. Maybe other people have more solutions than my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried clicking the following button?

[image]

Comment: @Marnix Yes. "I tried unchecking the file in the "filename" dropdown in the Script panel, but that doesn't do anything."<br/>Except in my Script panel. The drop down is the name of my jQuery file: jQuery.js, where yours is "firebug-and-jquery"

Comment: @Nicklamort: click the file you need to view

Comment: @Marnix Hmm, I just noticed that when I include the jquery file, it doesn't compile my inline js code..all my event handlers don't work. That must be the reason.. but why would it do that?

Comment: @Nicklamort You could check 2 things. First: check if the `console` tab tells you anything. If not, there is just a compiler error in your code. A missing `;` or what not. It doesn't always show you what is wrong with your code. And sometimes, just sometimes, you'll have to check in IE what your compiler errors are. But first, turn on your Console tab.

Comment: @Marnix The only error I get is when I try to click in my textbox. The `onfocus` js handler (thats missing) isn't defined. But when I don't include the jquery file, it works fine. The console isn't showing me any other errors, especially not in jquery, it is straight from the jquery website.

Comment: @Marnix Wow, I figured it out..thx for your help. I'll just give ya the answer in appreciation.

Comment: @Nicklamort, so you figured it all out? Is it really as in your question? That you need to include it behind the inline? Haven't had such problems ever...

Comment: @Marnix No.. I was including jquery with a self closing tag instead of `</script>` >_<

Answer (score 1):

if you have an inline piece of code it's easier to find in the 'HTML' tab of firebug.
just look for the `<script>` tag you have put on the page.

Comment: Thx. That made it obvious that my js code isn't even there, not even under the HTML tab. Please see my update in OP.

Answer (score 0):

You do not uncheck a file in it. The checkmark shows you what file is currently displayed in the console window.

Scroll down the list of files and find your JavaScript file and click on it. It will open up in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Under script tag you will find a list of .js files loaded for that particular page. just select it from the dropdown. The check you are talking about is for selecting a particular file from the dropdown.